# Accessing properties of fetched NSManagedObjects in loop causing high memory usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Our app offers an option to backup the `Core Data` records, and for this we use `XML`. To do this I make an `NSFetchRequest` in a backgroundContext and in a `performBlockAndWait` block. `items` are a `relationship` which I am pre-fetching.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"ZSSCDOfflineSet"];
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 50;
fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = @[@"items"];
```

Then I get the fetched objects and loop through them, creating the XML:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedResults = [privateContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSString *location;
for (ZSSCDOfflineSet *offlineSet in fetchedResults) {

    NSArray *items = offlineSet.geocaches.allObjects;


    // Write items to XML file using NSOutputStream
    [self writeItemsToDisk:items];

}
```

I am using an `NSOutputStream` to write the XML to disk, but the major memory usage seems to be (tested using Instruments) when I am accessing the properties of the `ZSSCDOfflineSet` object and creating an `NSString` that is then written to disk.

What is the reason for the high memory usage when accessing these core data object's properties? Have I done something wrong with the fetch that is causing this?

Comment: This could be a useless idea, but any time you loop and get high memory usage, the first thing to try is always to stick an autoreleasepool into the loop, so I'd try that first. :)

Comment: @matt I have tried that, sadly doesn't help.

Comment: I told you it could be useless! :(

Comment: Couple of tips ... 1) Refault already used objects with `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` 2) `reset` context periodically (see next point) 3) Add another loop and throw away fetch request and create a new one with `fetchLimit` & `fetchOffset` 4) Use `propertiesToFetch` to limit it to properties you're interested in.